# I did not get the job offer. What term could describe the brief sadness I experienced, then moving forward?

Tags: single-word-requests, semantics, business-language

I was turn downed for a job offer after an onsite interview. This was sad news for me. What term could describe the brief sadness I experienced upon notification that I did not make the cut for a job offer? The key difference here is that I was upset, but now I am feeling better after some hours passed in this situation.

Comment: A good single word 'euphemism' of our american psychology culture might be "absorbed" ... although it might not always mean bounce back but instead sink in.  I absorbed the bad news about the job offer in the morning and was able to get back in step by the afternoon" ?  I'm not so confident to make it an answer though.

Comment: Like resignation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You felt ***dejected***

> unhappy, disappointed, or without hope:
>   *She looked a bit dejected when they told her she didn't get the job.*
>   ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dejected))

Comment: @Tom22 - True. But English is not about having a single word to describe every possible complex concept.  English is designed to allow its users to combine multiple words to achieve their goals-  it’s much more efficient that way.  “I was dejected for a time, but I quickly got over it.”

Comment: Maybe it was a ***short-lived setback***?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come up with a single word but two similar idioms come to mind.

> [chin at dicitonary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/take--it--on--the--chin)
>
> Idioms
>
> **keep one's chin up**,
>
> to maintain a cheerful disposition in spite of difficulties, disappointments, etc.
>
> **take it on the chin**, Informal.
>
> to suffer defeat; fail completely.
>
> to endure suffering or punishment.

On the second one, **take it on the chin**  I know that term in a much more positive way.

> [**take sthing on the chin** at Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/take-somethinging-on-the-chin)
>   phrase [VERB inflects]
>
> If you say that someone took something on the chin, you mean that they accepted an unpleasant or difficult situation bravely and without making a lot of fuss about it.

My sense is even more positive than the second.

to me, **took it on the chin** means more of the positive outlook a great athlete would have to be able to come back from a setback.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a better term for a very wide event concerning multiple stages of emotion from a negative stimulus, I'd say you feel ***bummed out*** or just ***bummed***. This is, however, very colloquial and likely slang, however does convey the feeling that the dejection is temporary and only for some time, though only implicitly.

Consider using a more eloquent way of expressing this set of events, as it is essentially three separate events you're trying to encapsulate into a single word.